# It's possible to show up the "camera access window" more than once?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera, microphone

My app is embed into a page with other related infomation, so I want to, if the user denies the access, to go back some steps (in Flash) and asks again if he can allow access, but once you deny (or allow), Flash don't show this window again.

Today I'm calling a external JS to reload the SWF element, but it's not elegant.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can open the SecurityPanel in the privacy tab:

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
```

Comment: Yes, but is so different. I really need the "default".

Comment: Thanks. I'll still reloading my SWF.